# Theoretical properties of Gaussian Process Emulator

Tags: prediction, convergence, gaussian-process, approximation, asymptotics

I am studying Guassian Prcess Emulator (GPE) to approximate computationally expensive computer models. Basically, we suppose the computer model, or simulator, is denoted by $f(x)$, where $x$ is the vector of input parameters. Then the GPE assumes $f(\cdot)\sim GP(m(\cdot),C(\cdot,\cdot))$ with some appropriate mean function and covariance function. Then given a traning set, $D=\{(x_1,f(x_1)),...,(x_N,f(x_N))\}$, at any input $x_0$, the simulation value $f(x_0)$ can be approximated/predicted/interpolated based on the training set in the sense of a full probabilistic sense. For example usually it is approximated with $E(f(x_0)|D)$. If $x_0=x_j$, for some $j=1,...,N$, then this value is exactly $f(x_j)$, otherwise it is a prediction with some predictive variance.

After reading many papers on this topic, I found nearly all of them are talking about practical aspects, e.g. the specification of prior and calculation of posterior (Bayesian), or calculation of MLE (Frequentist), design, etc. I wonder if there are any literatures focusing on the theoretical parts, for example, how well $f(\cdot)$ is approximated with such statistical surrogate, the convergence rate in terms of $N$, the asymptotic properties, etc.

Would anyone by chance guide me to some literatures on any of these points? Many thanks!

Comment: I am not sufficiently qualified to provide an answer to this question. But I agree these question do not seem to attract not too much attention in the machine learning or computer experiments literature. References I found are: Rasmussen & Williams Chapter 7.1 and 7.2 in their book http://www.gaussianprocess.org/gpml/chapters/
and Chapter 11 of http://www.amazon.com/Scattered-Approximation-Monographs-Computational-Mathematics/dp/0521131014